# App crashes at second timer run

Tags: android, timer, crash, apk

I'm working on an Android app, and I want to update the background every 30 seconds.

I used a timer, and it works, but only once! The second time the app crashes.

```
public Timer mTimer = null;    

public void loadColor()
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.color);

        cur_scr = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.colorScreen);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) throws InterruptedException
    {
        int id = v.getId();

        switch (id)
        {
                case R.id.nextColor:
                    loadColor();

                    mTimer = new Timer();

                    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
                    {
                      public void run()
                      {
                         Random gen = new Random();
                         cur_scr.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, gen.nextInt(256), gen.nextInt(256), gen.nextInt(256)));
                      }
                    }, 0, 2000);

                    break;
        }
    }
```

LOGCAT:

```
05-10 15:46:12.325: W/dalvikvm(346): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
05-10 15:46:12.344: E/AndroidRuntime(346): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
05-10 15:46:12.344: E/AndroidRuntime(346): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
05-10 15:46:12.344: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2932)
05-10 15:46:12.344: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChild(ViewRoot.java:642)
05-10 15:46:12.344: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRoot.java:668)
05-10 15:46:12.344: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:2511)
05-10 15:46:12.344: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:5279)
05-10 15:46:12.344: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at android.view.View.setBackgroundDrawable(View.java:7626)
05-10 15:46:12.344: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at android.view.View.setBackgroundColor(View.java:7516)
05-10 15:46:12.344: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at com.haxad0x.tools.Core$1.run(Core.java:162)
05-10 15:46:12.344: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
05-10 15:46:14.194: D/AndroidRuntime(346): Shutting down VM
05-10 15:46:14.194: W/dalvikvm(346): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
05-10 15:46:14.194: I/Process(346): Sending signal. PID: 346 SIG: 9
```

Please help me! Thanks guys!

---

```
        case R.id.nextColor:
            loadColor();

            mTimer = new Timer();

            mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
            {
              public void run()
              {
                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                  {
                      public void run() {
                         Random gen = new Random();
                         cur_scr.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, gen.nextInt(256), gen.nextInt(256), gen.nextInt(256)));
                      }
                  });
              }
            }, 0, 2000);

            break;
```

The code works this way. I only have one question about it: is it a long code? I mean; does it affect performance because of all the voids and can I shorten it?

Comment: and the error message that it gives to you in the log cat is...? Also you shouldn't be trying to call findViewById() every 30 seconds. That is a relatively expensive method, call it once during your onCreate() and just keep the reference that you get around and call .setBackgroundcolor() as many times as you want on that reference.

Comment: did you really just use my solution, get it working, post it as your code now, not vote my post up or mark it accepted, and then ask for how to improve it when I clearly posted how to improve it in my post?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your timer is still around after your activity has been destroyed, and your view no longer exists (causing findViewById to fail), and you have a different view visible.

What you need to do is stop the timer in onDestroy for the activity.

Create your timer variable as a class level variable, perhaps mTimer..
So you'd have

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {
  private Timer mTimer = null;

  public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    //setContentView
    mTimer = new Timer();
    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
    {
      public void run()
      {
         Random gen = new Random();
         cur_scr = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.colorScreen);
         cur_scr.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, gen.nextInt(256), gen.nextInt(256), gen.nextInt(256)));
      }
    }, 0, 30000);
  } 

  public void onDestroy() {
    mTimer.cancel();
  }
}
```

-- Update -- 
While I still agree you should make the above changes, it looks like the TimerTask is run in a new thread (not the main UI thread). You need to run any code that works with the UI on the UI thread. Use [Activity.runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) like this:

```
mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
{
      public void run()
      {
         Random gen = new Random();
         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               //actually you should probably put a try catch around the code below so it doesn't crash your app if somehow the view isn't found any longer.. It should work as long as you remove the timer task on onDestroy but to be safe i would put a try catch in.
               cur_scr = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.colorScreen);
               cur_scr.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, gen.nextInt(256), gen.nextInt(256), gen.nextInt(256)));
            }
         });

      }
}
```

There is another way which is probably easier to do this using a Handler.

This is how I would do it:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {
  private static final int BG_CHANGE_INTERVAL = 30 * 1000;
  private Handler mHandler = null;
  private Runnable mUpdateBgRunnable = new Runnable() {
    Random gen = new Random();
    @Override
    public void run() {
      cur_scr = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.colorScreen);
      cur_scr.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, gen.nextInt(256), gen.nextInt(256), gen.nextInt(256)));
      updateBg();
    }

  }
  public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    //setContentView
    mHandler = new Handler();
    updateBg();
  } 

  private void updateBg() {
     mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateBgRunnable);
     mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateBgRunnable, BG_CHANGE_INTERVAL);
  }

  public void onDestroy() {
    mTimer.cancel();
  }
}
```

See this [article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html) for more info on handlers vs timers.

Comment: Hey guys! I added findViewById() in the onCreate() event. I also tried Matt Wolfe's suggestion but it keeps crashing. I can't post logcat because there are -700 characters left? How can I post it? Thanks!

Comment: does it crash everytime no matter what or just occassionally? If its always crashing you are probably getting a classcastexception which means the view you are looking up is not the right type... We at least need to see the stack trace of the error to get an idea.

Comment: No don't put code in a comment. Put the code in your question by using the edit button..

Comment: Did you ever figure out the problem?

Comment: sorry guys, I updated my code & logcat. can you see whats wrong? i think the timer runs in a new thread and cant access the view, but how can i fix this?